# (BOOL) webView... not firing on all requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm working on an iOS app using UIWebViews, and I'm running in to some interesting behavior.

I'm trying to load content from my website into an iOS app via a UIWebView, but I want to block certain calls made by the website (such as some of my analytics) to speed up the load within the WebView.  If I connect the device to a proxy (I've been using Charles Proxy) I can see these requests going out, just as I would expect them to.  However, for whatever reason,

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
```

Is not capturing the requests I'm looking for.  In fact, webView:(UIWebView *)... is only firing on about a third of the calls that I see going out over the proxy.

Does anyone know why that might be?  Or have any idea what I can do to intercept *all* of the calls made by a UIWebView?

Thank you

Comment: did you set the delegate?

Comment: Yes.  It fires maybe 12 times/page load, and I see closer to 40 requests go out over the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not get delegate calls for all requests from the web view (for example, resource requests, such as JavaScript and images).

To have a precise control over all requests, you will need to implement a `NSURLProtocol` in which you can decide what request to allow and what to block.